# What is the best way to define local variables dynamically in a method

Tags: python

When I call a function, I would like to be able to define dynamic variable names in the function, like so...

```
def build_ports(portlist):
    for idx, portname in enumerate(portlist):
        chassis, slot, port = portname.split('/') 
        vartxt = "p%i" % idx
        locals()[vartxt] = Port()  # Class defining a port object
        locals()[vartxt].port_method1(chassis, slot, port)
        if idx > 5:
            locals()[vartxt].port_method2()  # Only call this object method, if idx > 5
```

But we all know that `locals()` is read-only, unlike `globals()`... so the interpreter barfs when it sees `locals()[vartxt]`...

Is there any way to define dynamic variables in a method without polluting the global namespace (or worse, using a global variable in a method, when it was never defined in that method)?

Comment: why aren't you using "port" anywhere?

Comment: The assignment statement creates a local variable.  Why do anything else?  Your "variable named based on an index" is what dictionaries are for.  Why aren't you just using a simple `dict` for this?

Comment: @S. Lott, indeed that's what I should be doing, as I agreed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
locals()[vartxt] = Port()  # Class defining a port object
...
```

Don't use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)... use a dict.

Answer (score 6):

Use lists instead of this insanity called variable variables.

```
def build_ports(portlist)
    ports = []
    for idx, portname in enumerate(portlist):
        ports.append(Port())
        ports[-1].port_method1()
        if idx > 5:
            ports[-1].port_method2()
```

Instead of using `ports[-1]`, you might instead scrap the unused `portname` iteration variable and create a local `portname = Port()`, use that to call the methods and then append it to `ports` at the end. What *is* `portlist` anyway?

Comment: I second this - though the entire logic of this function does escape me. You could use a `dict` instead of a list if you really wanted named variables

Comment: @Stefano, `portlist` is a text list of port names... example, `['1/5/9', '2/7/13']`... those are used to build a corresponding port object.  I don't like managing lists of anonymous objects... the dict with a dynamic key name is an interesting option.

Comment: thanks @Mike, I guess with the complete unsimplified code it would make more sense, and @delnan questions would have been answered too! Are you satisfied enough with his answer, or something still not working? Why not going simply with the local `port` object as he suggests?

Comment: I edited to reflect a more exact use of the function... as you can see, everything gets used.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. If you look at how Python stores local variables, you can see why.

Global variables are stored in a hash table, which is dynamically-sized, and the names are compiled into hash keys (in Python parlance, interned strings). This makes global lookups comparatively "slow", but since one needs to find globals by name from other compilation units (modules), it's required:

```
# a.py
x = 3

# b.py
import a
a.x = 4 # b needs to know how to find the same x!
```

Local variables are stored in a fixed-size array and the names are compiled into array indices.

This can be seen when you look at the bytecode, which has LOAD_FAST and STORE_FAST for locals but LOAD_GLOBAL and STORE_GLOBAL for globals. It also leaks through in the different exceptions you get. Globals trickle up and generate a NameError when not found, but undefined locals are detected by an empty slot, giving an UnboundLocalError.

```
def foo():
    a
    a = 1
foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

def foo():
    a = 1
foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Because the array is fixed-size, and the size is computed while compiling the function, you cannot create any additional locals.

If you need more "locals", you'll need to store the values as named attributes of an object or in a dictionary; obviously that will also negate the speed benefits.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec).

Edit: Yes, I meant exec.

Comment: -1 **No.** Even if it technically worked (it doesn't - you need `exec` for assignment)... there's a perfectly clean, performant, idiomatic, obvious solution right at hand!

Comment: @delnan: Yes, I meant exec. Thanks.